# How to recognise input ranges that result customer dissatisfaction?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, prediction

I'm looking for a machine learning method to recognize input ranges that result customer dissatisfaction.

For instance, assume that we have a database of customer's age, customer's gender, date and time that customer stops by, person who is in charge of providing service to customer, etc. and finally a number in range of 0 to 10 which stands for customer satisfaction (Extracted from customer's feedback).

Now I'm looking for a method to determine input ranges which results dissatisfaction. For example male customers who are stopping by John, between 10-12pm are mainly dissatisfied.

I believe there already is a kind of clustering or neural network method for this purpose. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one method to do it (correlation analysis for ex.)

One simple way is to classify your data by the degree of satisfaction (target)

**Classes**:

- 0-5 DISSATISFIED
- 6-10 SATISFIED

Than look for repetition along features in each cluster.

**For example**:

- if you are interested by one feature, ex: the person who stopped clients, than just get the most frequent name within the two classes to get a result like `80% of unsatisfied client was stopped by jhon`
- if you are interested by more than one feature, ex: the person who stopped the client AND the time of the day, in this case you can consider the couple of features us one and do the same thing as the first case, than you will get something like `30% of unsatisfied client was stopped by jhon between 10 and 11 am`

Comment: Do you mean finding frequent itemsets in each class (Satisfied & Dissatisfied)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a clustering problem. You have training data.

Instead, you may be looking for a decision tree.

Comment: In decision tree I should classify my continuous inputs myself. I'm looking for a method which recognize the range itself. For instance, I want it to say that customers between 23 to 27 are not satisfied with a specific service provider.

Comment: decision trees can do that. it's just more expensive and fragile than binary attributes.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to know? Which service person to fire, what are the best hours to provide the service, or sth. else? I mean what are your classes?

Provided, you what to evaluate the service person - the classes are the
persons.  In SVM (and I think for NN applies the same) I would split all not purely numerical data in boolean attributes.

- Age: unchanged, number
- Gender: male 1/0, female 1/0
- Date: 7 features for days of week, possibly the number of experience days of the service person. for each special date an attribute e.g. national holiday 1/0
- Time: split the time-span in reasonable ranges e.g. 15 min. Each range is a feature
- Satisfaction: unchanged - number 1-10

With this model you could predict the satisfaction index for each service person for given date, time, gender, age.

Comment: Eventually, I want to have a system, which gets the database, analyses it and finally gives me some recommendation according to concentration of customers' dissatisfaction. For instance, the system output would be like this: Female customers who stop by at 10 to 12pm and are between 30 to 35 years old usually are not satisfied with John.

Comment: Why do you want to apply ML here at all? Sum dissatisfaction per service person, group by categories of interest, compare the counts.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can try using anomaly detection algorithms. Basically if you consider the satisfaction level as the dependent variable, then you can try to find the samples which are located away from the majority of the samples in the euclidean space. These away samples could signify dissatisfaction.